# In the AnalogRead example, would the thing work if I remove or short the A0 and the ground pin?

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, electronics

What I want to know is that how exactly does analogRead work because I have want to use it with a flex sensor and it has only two pins.I tried to find other examples on the internet, but this is the only example I find.If the middle pin of the 10k potentiometer and a0 pin are shorted or the gnd  pin is removed altogether,then would this thing work?

Comment: You did not show us the example which is confusing you.

Comment: I moved this to the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused because the ADC input measures voltage, not resistance.

To convert from resistance to voltage you need to pull in the opposite direction on the variable resistance with a fixed resistor.  As in the following image from [this tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/flex-sensor-hookup-guide).

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...the image said it all....thank you...